# Backtracking recursion to find a path from source to destination in 2D array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I am trying to find a possible path inside 2D array and I have a source point (x,y) and a destination point (destX, destY).

I am trying to do it in a backtracking recursion way since I don't care about finding the *shortest* path, all I care about is finding a path.

The problem is that somehow within the algorithm it goes right to a corner and gets stuck there... So I guess I wrote something incorrectly logic wise.

The recursion function:

```
$scope.findPath = function(x, y, destX, destY) {
        console.log("x: " + x + ", y: " + y);
        if(x >= $scope.buttons.length || x < 0 || y >= $scope.buttons[0].length || y < 0) {
            return false;
        }

        if(x == destX && y == destY) {
            return true;
        }

        if(!$scope.checkIfButtonEmpty(x, y)) {
            console.log("location not empty")
            return false;
        }

        $scope.solution[x][y].marked = true;

        if($scope.findPath(x + 1, y, destX, destY) === true) {
            return true;
        }
        if($scope.findPath(x, y + 1, destX, destY) === true) {
            return true;
        }
        if($scope.findPath(x - 1, y, destX, destY) === true) {
            return true;
        }
        if($scope.findPath(x, y - 1 , destX, destY) === true) {
            return true;
        }

        $scope.solution[x][y].marked = false;

        return false;
    };
```

The function that calls the recursion, and after finding a path and writing it into a boolean 2D array is supposed to print the path graphically:

```
$scope.startDrawingConnection = function() {
        if($scope.startLocation.length == 2 && $scope.endLocation.length == 2){
            $scope.findPath($scope.startLocation[0], $scope.startLocation[1], $scope.endLocation[0], $scope.endLocation[1]);
            console.log("Finished finding path");
            $scope.drawPath();
            console.log("Finished drawing path");
        }
    };
```

Please help me figure out what I did wrong in the algorithm.

Comment: Any chance that `$scope.startLocation[0]` and `$scope.startLocation[1]` are strings instead of numbers?

Comment: @RickHitchcock Nope. I am certain the problem in general isn't coming from syntax/typing issues, and other than that $scope.startLocation is an array I define in code I did not show here.

The thing is that the code does run, and the recursion runs for a few calls until it gets into a corner and gets trapped inside it, so it must be a logical error I made while writing the recursion function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you will be running in circles, visiting nodes you had already tried before (without success), and trying them again.

The search should never have to visit the same square twice. So keep track of where you have been before, in such a way that you don't wipe out that trace when backtracking, and never again start a search from that square again.

This you can achieve by adding an additional property in your solution nodes, and add these two lines of code just before you mark a node with `marked = true`:

```
    if ($scope.solution[x][y].visited) return false;
    $scope.solution[x][y].visited = true;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the simple solution! I tried it before but I guess the order and the place in which I wrote these lines made it not work.

Now if I want to find the shortest path, is there a way to refactor the code I have already written or do I have to write a completely new solution utilizing some algorithm like Bellman ford, Dijkstra, etc.?

Comment: DFS is not the most efficient if you want to find the shortest path. In an extreme case where the target is just one step away, a DFS search could visit the whole grid before realising it was just there. So, yes, you would be looking to BFS-based algorithms. You could for instance look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46395006/5459839)